# VLC over VNC to iPhone VLC window ok with monitor connected but when headless VLC window clipped at top and bottom

Tags: raspbian, vnc, vlc

rpi B+ latest raspbian and RealVNC iPhone 6 with latest
With monitor attached works fine. Subsequent headless 
operation has all objects appearing larger and top and 
bottom of VLC window clipped

Comment: What are "latest" versions in a year? Nobody knows. You should refer to the version.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your iPhone resolution (or smaller) as the default in config.txt and reboot.

VNC is temperamental when no monitor is connected and resolution is not set.

You can set the resolution by running

```
sudo raspi-config
Option 7 / A5
```

or by hand following the [instructions here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md)